# Android touch event force closes

Tags: java, android

I have a 2d array displaying on the screen and decided to implement a method where it would detect the touch location and find the tile in which the touch is located and remove it, r more precisely, change the int at map[x][y].
I currently have a 2d map array full of 3s 15 by 15.
Touch a location and this method, which i created because I could not find a way to round down numbers, would calculate the position in the array and change the value:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    mX = (int) event.getX();
    mY = (int) event.getY();
    calculate();
    return true;
}

public void calculate() {

    indexX = 0;
    indexY = 0;
    for (int n = 32; n < mX; n += 32) {
        indexX++;
    }
    for (int n = 32; n < mY; n += 32) {
        indexY++;
    }
    map[indexY][indexX] = 1;
}
```

It'll force close if I starting mashing the screen or dragging my finger around, but if I touch a single location one by one slowly it works fine.
I assumed the method to calculate should not be in the touch event method but still am not quite sure.

Comment: Could you please paste the logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for this for loop.  Dividing two integers should give you an integer result.  Since you want to divide by a power of two you could also use the arithmetic shift operator.  (One might think the compiler would pick whichever is faster regardless of what you code, but the rounding behavior for negative values is different)

indexX = mX >> 5;

Speed shouldn't be an issue if you are only doing two operations anyway.

By "force closes" do you mean an application not responding dialog?

If it's something else, you might have a bounds problem.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. The first solution I came up with was to divide to integers like you suggested but it was not working. I guess it was because I had my phone plugged in AND an emulator running or something of that sort. I'm going to try this again and see what happens.

Comment: I pressed "enter" accidently before finishing typing and submitted a comment =|. BTW what do you mean by bounds problem. I ran my app again and when start touching random spots really fast it force closes...

Comment: You still haven't posted the logcat or explained what exactly you mean by 'force closes' - what is the error?   As for bounds, you have no check that the index you calculate is within the bounds of the array.

Comment: Ah it was a bounds problem -.- Not sure how I overlooked that. Can't seem to get a logcat...